# Getting 429 from IPFS backend

Tags: ipfs

I am relatively new to Dapps and IPFS. Was trying out fetching an IPFS asset and I am getting 429 for my requests. This is somehow related to my IP, as I am able to successfully fetch from my friend's IP. Somehow my IP has been rate limited I guess.

Is there any way I can get whitelisted for IPFS. Does it get solved if I host my own IPFS node ?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>429 Too Many Requests</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>429 Too Many Requests</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
        <center>openresty</center>
    </body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

The response headers also doesn't to return anything useful.

```
access-control-allow-headers →X-Requested-With, Range, Content-Range, X-Chunked-Output, X-Stream-Output
access-control-allow-methods →GET, POST, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin →*
access-control-expose-headers →Content-Range, X-Chunked-Output, X-Stream-Output
content-length →568
content-type →text/html
date →Mon, 02 Aug 2021 05:51:56 GMT
server →openresty
strict-transport-security →max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-ipfs-pop →gateway-bank3-sg1
```

Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hitting a gateway throttle, it sounds like you're doing requests from a centralised location (as you mentioned, mostly from your own IP). If possible, you can decentralise that access out, having the clients the users are using (if a website, that'd be in the web page) access the gateway you're using themselves, where the HTTP requests are coming from their PCs, rather than all coming from the one server.

However you're also correct when you ask:

> Does it get solved if I host my own IPFS node ?

Yes it does get solved, as you're actually using IPFS at that point, instead of just a gateway (HTTP). Your node will pull the data from several other nodes, instead of *just* that one gateway node.